# Div css not getting applied to layout. Why am I doing wrong?

Tags: css

I'm currently changing from table based layouts to use div layout instead.  I'm struggling with the css.  My styles just don't seem to be getting applied even though the css file is loading.  What am I doing wrong?

```
.CategoryHeader
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #2151b1;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-top:3px;
}

.CriteriaHeader {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-top:3px;
}

.divTable {
        display: table;
        border: none;
        width:100%;

}

.divTR {
        display: table-row;
        width: 100%;    

    }

.divTD {
    display: table-cell;
    margin-bottom:22px;
    }


<div class="divTable">        
    <div class="divTR">       
        <div class="divTD">
             <LABEL class="CriteriaHeader">Number</LABEL>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTR"> 
        <div class="divTD">
             <asp:TextBox id="txtNumber" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox" ToolTip="Enter Number to search"></asp:TextBox>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="divTR">       
        <div class="divTD">
            <LABEL class="CriteriaHeader">Description</LABEL>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="divTR">      
        <ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender ID="cboDesc_ListSearchExtender" runat="server" 
            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="cboDesc" PromptCssClass="ListSearch">
        </ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender>            
        <div class="divTD">
            <asp:DropDownList id="cboDesc" runat="server" CssClass="DropDownList" ToolTip="Choose description to search"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>      

<div>
        <asp:Button id="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="Button"></asp:Button>&nbsp;
        <asp:Button id="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" CssClass="Button"></asp:Button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you say which properties are not being applied?

Comment: Post the rendered HTML and create a jsFiddle

Comment: please post the link to your css file also

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using so many table property, you can use `position:relative`/`absolute`/`fixed`, `display:inline`/`inline-block`. They are absolutely compatible with IE6+ and non-IE browsers. Like table、table-row、table-cell，they are not absolutely for IE browser.